# Moving eclipse with plugins to another pc

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I have installed `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development` plugins to my Eclipse Indigo (windows 7 machine). Now, I can create Web project using `File>>New>>Other>>Web>>Dynamic Web Project` .

I have copied eclipse to my new PC (windows XP) and started it. Unfortunately I can't find 'Dynamic Web Project' in menu. Why there is no such menu? I supposed that eclipse keeps everything in its folder. Should I also copy `.metadata` folder that is in my working space?

I decided to re install needed plugins in new pc, but got a lot of errors that are related to "... plugin already installed".

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: As a sidenote, have a look at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/kick-your-eclipse-cloud-plug. That allows you to have separate installations, but keeping them in sync with regards to configurations and installed plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both pc have same arhitecture and same OS. then you can copy paste with no problems.
Otherwise - you platform -wich is a plugin will not work on the other pc. You can choose to export a bookmarks of xml from update sites and reinstall all of them, but in case that there are some plugins copied by hand this will not work.

You cannot find Dynamic web Project because you don't have WTP installed

Comment: 'from PC' is windows 7; 'to pc' is windows xp. But I have installed WTP in 'from PC' Is it possible that house plugins can work in win 7 and can't in win XP?

Comment: That isn't possible. Copy the whole eclipse folder and try to start it, check your eclipse.ini file for setting up vm location if needed.